# C++ Минимальный простой делитель (задача)

Tags: c++

### Задача:

> Дано целое число, **не меньшее 2**. Выведите его наименьший простой делитель.
> Входные данные: вводится целое положительное число **N≤2∗10(9)**.
> Выходные данные: выведите ответ на задачу.

---

Вот мой код, но тестирующая система его не принимает =(
*P.S: Не предлагайте, пожалуйста, сложный код. Я новичок и хочу разобраться в своих ошибках.*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    int n, i = 3;
    cin >> n;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        cout << 2;
    while (n % i != 0 && i * i <= n) {
        i += 2;
    }
    if (i * i <= n)
        cout << i;
    else
        cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что пишет система ? неверный вывод, истекло время, или что-то еще может ?

Comment: Честно говоря, почему-то ничего. Просто красный код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы не выходите из функции (в данном случае и программы) когда число делится на 2. Программа продолжает поиск делителя.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    int n, i = 3;
    cin >> n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        cout << 2;
        return 0; // <-------
    }
    while (n % i != 0 && i * i <= n) {
        i += 2;
    }
    if (i * i <= n)
        cout << i;
    else
        cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Долго мучался с этой задачкой))